# How do I add sounds to my Yamaha psrew300?

Tags: piano, key, keyboard, sound, digital-piano

I watched a YouTube video of someone using a sound effect as a piano on there keyboard. I was wondering how to add sounds to my keyboard. Also can you do it with a mobile device?

Answer (score 1):

The PSR-EW300 does not let you add sounds to its internal library, however it can act as a midi controller so you can trigger samples with it. The manual has info on how to use the USB to HOST connector for this.